# Como encontrar una frase dentro de una lista

Tags: python-3.x

Lo que quiero hacer es encontrar dentro de un archivo **.txt** una palabra, y de encontrarla, que me arroje esa respuesta.

Entonces, basado en éste código:

```
with open(compare_files + backups[bk]) as f, open(golden_config) as gc:
                
    flines = f.read().splitlines()
    glines = gc.read().splitlines()
```

Mando abrir un archivo txt de un directorio ya previamente definido, al abrirlo todo lo escrito ahí lo convierte en una lista *(flines)* la cuál es separada por saltos de línea.

> El archivo, es un archivo de configuración de un equipo.

Golden_config es otro txt donde escribo la palabra o palabras que quiero que encuentre. En este caso, me gustaría encontrar: **"State: current DEAD"**

Debido a que quiero comprar diferentes respaldos de configuraciones, cada equipo tiene diferentes valores.

Por ejemplo, un equipo puede tener **"State: current DEAD time: 6s"**, otro puede tener **"State: current DEAD ime 29s"**, otro puede estar en **"State: UP"** por lo cuál, encontrar el valor exacto en todos los equipos no es posible. Por lo mismo solo quiero buscar con el valor parcial de **"State: current DEAD"**

De otra pregunta intenté lo siguiente:

```
    print(flines)
    
    pista = ["-"]*len(flines)

    print("".join(pista))

    letra = "State: current DEAD"

    for c in re.finditer(letra, flines, re.IGNORECASE):
        pista[c.start()] = c.group()

    print("".join(pista))
```

Al correrlo me arroja el siguiente error:

> ```
>    Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "comparar.py", line 41, in <module>
>       for c in re.finditer(letra, flines, re.IGNORECASE):
>     File "C:\Python3\lib\re.py", line 246, in finditer
>       return _compile(pattern, flags).finditer(string)
>    TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
> ```

¿Qué opciones podría usar para poder solucionar esta duda?

Les agradecería mucho el apoyo.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import re
with open("fichero.txt","r") as f:
    for l in f:
        m = re.match(r".*State(.*).*time",l)
        if m:
            print(m.group(1))
```

Esto imprimiria por ejemplo " current DEAD" necesitarias dos palabras para acotar el mensaje, por un lado tienes "State" pero te hace falta una que determine el final.

Un saludo

Comment: Jorge, muchas gracias por tu respuesta!
No me corrigió la problemática pero me dió la guía de por donde buscar y ya lo hice funcionar.
Te agradezco bastante!